# Is the continued fraction of a constructible number special in some way?

Tags: diophantine-equations, continued-fractions, solvable-groups, modular-group

Rationals have finite CF and quadratic have periodic CF. CF in turn can be represented in terms of the modular group SL2(Z), e.g. using the standard generators S(z)=-1/z and T(z)=z+1. On the other hand constructible numbers in the sense of Gauss-Wantzel Theorem play an important role; is there something special about their CF in terms of S and T?